# pywintypes.com_error in Python during Excel import

Tags: python, excel, operating-system

I get this error on running my module gasprop. I do not understand what the error means and how to fix it:

```
import gasprop
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "gasprop.py", line 13, in <module>
sheet = wb.Sheets("Input1")
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\gen_py\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x6\Sheets.py", line 113, in __call__
ret = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(0, LCID, 2, (9, 0), ((12, 1),),Index
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147352565), None)
```

And here is my module gasprop:

```
import win32com.client, os
xl = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")
thisdir = os.getcwd()
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(thisdir+"/Input1.xlsx")
sheet = wb.Sheets("Input1")

......

def megaverify(self):
    listtr,listp=[],[]
    for i in range(16):
        tr=float(sheet.Range("D"+str(5+i)).Value)
        p=float(sheet.Range("C"+str(5+i)).Value)
        listtr.append(tr);listp.append(p)

    return tr, p
```

Comment: I used xlrd and that works for now, though, I would like to know the issue here

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this teсhnique to get more information about error:

```
import win32api
e_msg = win32api.FormatMessage(-2147352565)
print e_msg.decode('CP1251')
```

The message you get means that your excel file does not have a sheet with the name `"Input1"`. You can simply rename it.

Comment: Hey, I tried using the code you added, but am getting a syntax error on 'e_msg.decode('CP1251'). Any suggestions?

Comment: @ScoutEU Add parenthesis around it

Answer (score 3):

The error occurred because the sheet I wanted to call from the excel workbook did not match the name I was referencing it by in my python code. My sheet was actually Sheet1 (by default in excel) but I was calling a sheet Input1 as seen in line 5 of my module gasprop. The mismatch in names caused this error.