# python win32client package trying to manipulate excel column color

Tags: python, excel, pywin32

i am scratching data from web and trying to write new data to excel.The script does it succesfully. But what I observed nor pandas and not openpyxl has an attribute to preserve already excel sheet colors. That's why after researching web i chose to work with win32 package.

Code at the ends opens up many excel objects but does not open file. Error is `pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147352565), None)`

code is below;

```
import pandas as pd


import openpyxl

import win32com.client
app=win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
app.Interactive=True
app.Visible=True
wb=app.Workbooks('./outputFile/output.xlsx')
ws=wb.Worksheets('URLS P1')


ws.Range('A1:G1').Interior.Color=RGB(155,192,0)
```

Comment: Please add the full traceback to be clear which line triggers the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24326638/470477), the error code you're getting apparently indicates that the worksheet name isn't correct. Try `Sheet1` instead of `URLS P1`.